# Can you execute two javascript functions with one submit button

Tags: javascript, html

I have two different option boxes in my form and then two different scripts to pull this data on the click is this how I execute both scripts or will this not work?

```
<input class="form-control" type="button" onclick="fun() && fun2()" value="Submit">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes, make it

```
<input class="form-control" type="button" onclick="fun(); fun2();" value="Submit">
```

or you can call one function which will call both of them

```
<input class="form-control" type="button" onclick="fun();" value="Submit">

function fun()
{
  fun1();
  fun2();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes thats pretty easy:

```
function myFunction(){
  functionOne();
  functionTwo();
}
```

Then you can simply call myFunction on the onklick attribute